# Keep getting error: "0/2 nodes are available: 2 pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims."

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, digital-ocean, persistent-volumes, kubernetes-statefulset

I'm trying to setup an elasticsearch stateful set. I realise there a some similar questions that have been asked but none help in my circumstance.

The first version of setting up an elasticsearch stateful set worked fine with the following config:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch-volume
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: do-block-storage
  capacity:
    storage: 100M
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/data/elasticsearch"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim # Create PVC
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch-volume-claim # Sets PVC's name
  labels:
    app: elasticsearch # Defines app to create PVC for
spec:
  storageClassName: do-block-storage
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 100M # Sets PVC's size
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: elasticsearch
  ports:
    - port: 9200 # To get at the elasticsearch container, just hit the service on 9200
      targetPort: 9200 # routes to the exposed port on elasticsearch
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch # name of stateful
  namespace: default
spec:
  serviceName: elasticsearch
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: elasticsearch # should match service > spec.slector.app.
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: elasticsearch
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: elasticsearch-pvc
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: elasticsearch-volume-claim
      containers:
        - name: elasticsearch
          image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.2.3
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 100m
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9200
              name: rest
              protocol: TCP
            - containerPort: 9300
              name: inter-node
              protocol: TCP
          volumeMounts:
            - name: elasticsearch-pvc
              mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
          env:
            - name: cluster.name
              value: search
            - name: node.name
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.name
            - name: discovery.type
              value: single-node
            - name: ES_JAVA_OPTS
              value: "-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
            - name: xpack.security.enabled
              value: "false"
      initContainers:
        - name: fix-permissions
          image: busybox
          command:
            ["sh", "-c", "chown -R 1000:1000 /usr/share/elasticsearch/data"]
          securityContext:
            privileged: true
          volumeMounts:
            - name: elasticsearch-pvc
              mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
        - name: increase-vm-max-map
          image: busybox
          command: ["sysctl", "-w", "vm.max_map_count=262144"]
          securityContext:
            privileged: true
        - name: increase-fd-ulimit
          image: busybox
          command: ["sh", "-c", "ulimit -n 65536"]
          securityContext:
            privileged: true
```

I then tried to implement a version of this with multiple replica's:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: elasticsearch
  ports:
    - port: 9200 # To get at the elasticsearch container, just hit the service on 9200
      targetPort: 9200 # routes to the exposed port on elasticsearch
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: es-cluster # name of stateful
spec:
  serviceName: elasticsearch
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: elasticsearch # should match service > spec.slector.app.
  volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: elasticsearch-pvc
        labels:
          app: elasticsearch
      spec:
        accessModes:
          - ReadWriteOnce
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 100M
        storageClassName: do-block-storage
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: elasticsearch
    spec:
      # volumes:
      #   - name: elasticsearch-pvc
      #     persistentVolumeClaim:
      #       claimName: elasticsearch-volume-claim
      containers:
        - name: elasticsearch
          image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.2.3
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 100m
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9200
              name: rest
              protocol: TCP
            - containerPort: 9300
              name: inter-node
              protocol: TCP
          volumeMounts:
            - name: elasticsearch-pvc
              mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
          env:
            - name: cluster.name
              value: search
            - name: node.name
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: metadata.name
          - name: discovery.seed_hosts
            value: "es-cluster-0.elasticsearch,es-cluster-1.elasticsearch,es-cluster-2.elasticsearch"
          - name: cluster.initial_master_nodes
            value: "es-cluster-0,es-cluster-1,es-cluster-2"
          - name: ES_JAVA_OPTS
            value: "-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      initContainers:
        - name: fix-permissions
          image: busybox
          command:
            ["sh", "-c", "chown -R 1000:1000 /usr/share/elasticsearch/data"]
          securityContext:
            privileged: true
          volumeMounts:
            - name: elasticsearch-pvc
              mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
        - name: increase-vm-max-map
          image: busybox
          command: ["sysctl", "-w", "vm.max_map_count=262144"]
          securityContext:
            privileged: true
        - name: increase-fd-ulimit
          image: busybox
          command: ["sh", "-c", "ulimit -n 65536"]
          securityContext:
            privileged: true
```

However I ran into the error: `0/2 nodes are available: 2 pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims.`

I subsequently reduced the replica's to just 1 and manually created the PV in case DO was having an issue creating the PVC without a PV (even though DO should dynamically create the PVC and PV because it works with the postgres multi-replica stateful set which I set up in exactly the same way):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: es-volume-1
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 100M
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: do-block-storage
  hostPath:
    path: "/data/elasticsearch"
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions:
            - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
              operator: In
              values:
                - es-cluster-0
```

This again yielded the error: `0/2 nodes are available: 2 pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims.`

After spending a while de-bugging I gave up and decided to revert back to my single replica elasticsearch stateful set using the method I had originally used.

But once again I got the error `0/2 nodes are available: 2 pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims.`!!!

I don't have a clue what's going on here. Why am I getting this error even though I'm only trying to create a single replica and I *have* manually defined the PV and PVC which worked fine before??

Comment: do you have any default `storage class` configured in your cluster ? do `kubectl get sc`. I suspect not, or it's not working.

Comment: Annoyingly it was down to limits on storage capacity that can be configured in DO.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was indeed Digital Ocean specific. In the second attempt when I tried to create multiple replica's I had to use dynamic volume provisioning via `volumeClaimTemplates` and set the storage class to `do-block-storage` which as it turns out has a **minimum limit of 1Gi**!

Alas when I updated to 1Gi it all started working.